# How to get purchase status for specific list of items in Google Play IAB Version 3?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a problem with getting purchase status for my in app products. In my app I have hundreds of of in-app items and I just need to query 10 at the time. On my current account I have 20+ test purchased items (don't know the exact number) that I managed to buy.

The problem is if I pass only 1 `sku` to the `queryInventoryAsync` method I get `10-15` purchases back in the response and If I try to pass 10 `skus` I get **developer error (5).**

I use (not actual code):

```
List<String> skus = new ArrayList<String>();
skus.add("com.myapp.app_key.inappgroup.itemnumber");
mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skus, new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener()...
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I try to use

```
mIabHelper.getService().getSkuDetails((3, context.getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

I get the correct number of `sku` details back, but that does not help me much since I need to get purchase status.

Hope I make some sense & thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue with a fix described here: [Android IAB: "Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of items)" Developer Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346030/android-iab-error-refreshing-inventory-querying-prices-of-items-developer-e)

Just that in my case, the sku limit was 8 skus. Now it takes a little longer, but I get all the information I requested.